# How can your current SQL query refer back to a previous query without writing aliases in the query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, reference, subquery, alias

I am taking the Google Data Analytics course on Coursera and in the video the instructor executed the following query:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  Region,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM
  `class-5-355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
```

After executing this query they then opened a different editor window on BigQuery and executed the following query referring to an alias in the query above without defineing it:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  `class-5-355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
WHERE
  Total_Bags != Total_Bags_Calc
```

When I executed this query it did not work for me and I received this error: **'Unrecognized name: Total_Bags_Calc; Did you mean Total_Bags?'**

This makes sense. Within this query, the alias 'Total_Bags_Calc' hadn't been used within that query and didn't have anything to pull, so I tried a workaround:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  Region,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  (SELECT Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags FROM `class-5355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices`) AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM `class-5-355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
WHERE
  Total_Bags != Total_Bags_Calc
```

From what I understood this should work since the subquery now held the alias 'Total_Bags_Calc' but I still received the error **Unrecognized name: Total_Bags_Calc; Did you mean Total_Bags?**

How can I make this query work, and is there any way to have a query reference another query in the same manner that theirs did in the example?

Comment: Youre close! Instead of putting that subquery in the SELECT clause,  put it in the FROM clause so you can then select from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to select `FROM` the result of your first query, so try moving that subquery into the `FROM` clause.

For example,

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  {{ your other query goes here }}
WHERE
  Total_Bags != Total_Bags_Calc
```

Which would be:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(SELECT
  Date,
  Region,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM
  `class-5-355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
) as subquery
WHERE
  Total_Bags != Total_Bags_Calc
```

This is a really helpful technique to learn, so definitely learn it. However since you're doing something rather simple, you can actually get away with just coding that logic in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
  Date,
  Region,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM
  `class-5-355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
WHERE (Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags) <> Total_Bags
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I really appreciate the variety of options you gave for me to experiment with in your answer, and I look forward to diving into each of them and breaking each of them down.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning Tituslcuster!

I think I have spotted the issue.
Your query is creating an column named Total_Bags_Calc
When your code reaches the Where statement stuff, Total_Bags_Calc is the part that is breaking your code.
This is because it doesn't exist in the From table, but it does exist as a temporary name.
You can do two different things to fix this..
You can subquery this whole query, and do the Where Total_Bags_Calc on the outside query.
Or you can replace the Total_Bags_Calc with the actual formula that you used to calculate Total_Bags_Calc.

Here try this one:

```
select x2.* from (
  SELECT
  Date,
  Region,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  ( Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags ) AS Total_Bags_Calc
  FROM 'class-5-355317.avocado_data.avocado_prices'
 ) as x2
where x2.Total_Bags != x2.Total_Bags_Calc
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just ran this and it worked excellently. I am continually surprised by the versatility of subqueries across SQL clauses, and obviously I still have a lot to learn. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you :) Can you one up the usefulness my answer please :)

Comment: I would if I could, but I don’t have enough influence on stack overflow to upvote yet. :( as soon as I get to 15 I’ll come back and give you an upvote